# Merging small polygons with biggest adjacent polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge

I have a polygon shapefile classifieds in different regions. In each region there are many small polygons that I'd like to merge to the biggest polygon adjacent to each one of them, as long as these polygons belong to the same region.

I don't want that polygons neighbors located in different region be united.

I'm looking for an automatic solution. I tried eliminate tools but ArcGIS does not differentiate the union between regions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Modelbuilder](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/what-is-modelbuilder.htm) with [Iterate Feature Selection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-selection.htm) on region, [Eliminate](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate.htm) each region selection and finally merge all outputs.

Comment: Hi @BERA. I have a problem. I use Modelbuilder with Feature Selectios on region, but them i need select inside each region polygons with area<2ha  to use eliminate and to merge to the biggest polygon adjacent inside his region. I dont know how can i do it.